# Jenkins won't save global tool configuration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Currently trying to install the groovy plugin on Jenkins, but for some reason whenever I configure a groovy installer (or ant installer, other things are also not saving), after I apply/save and leave the page, when I come back it's blank, like I did nothing. What could this be?

By the way, the Jenkins server is running on a Mac.

Edit: Pictures

[image: Everytime I go to the page]
[image: After pressing new installation]

Edit 2: config.XML with userRemoteConfigs section removed

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<flow-definition plugin="workflow-job@2.1">
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>
      <strategy class="hudson.tasks.LogRotator">
        <daysToKeep>-1</daysToKeep>
        <numToKeep>20</numToKeep>
        <artifactDaysToKeep>-1</artifactDaysToKeep>
        <artifactNumToKeep>-1</artifactNumToKeep>
      </strategy>
    </jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>
  </properties>
  <definition class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition" plugin="workflow-cps@2.2">
    <scm class="hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM" plugin="git@2.4.4">
      <configVersion>2</configVersion>
      <branches>
        <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
          <name>*</name>
        </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
      </branches>
      <doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>false</doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>
      <submoduleCfg class="list"/>
      <extensions/>
    </scm>
    <scriptPath>Android/btMobileApp/Jenkins_Dev</scriptPath>
  </definition>
  <triggers>
    <hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger>
      <spec>H/2 * * * *</spec>
      <ignorePostCommitHooks>false</ignorePostCommitHooks>
    </hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger>
  </triggers>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
</flow-definition>
```

Answer (score 5):

Configuring the installer from Manage Jenkins does not actually install the tool immediately. It will be installed when you run a job that utilizes that tool. The configuration page also has a tendency to hide details when you reload the page. For example, on my server I have an Ant installation, but not a Groovy Installation. You can tell the difference on the config page by which button appears.
[Example Configure System Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESHYA.png)

If you don't have anything configured, you will see an "Add {tool}" button, otherwise the button will say "{tool} installations...". You can click the "{tool} installations..." button and it should expand to show your configurations.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I don't think it's going to help. I ran the job that uses groovy after configuring again, and I ran into the same error message, that groovy does not exist as a command.

Comment: When you go into the Configure System page, do you see the Groovy Installations button? If so, when you expand it what does that look like? A screenshot would help. Also, make sure that you're referencing that groovy install from the job.

Comment: Referencing it from the job? Can you expand on where that would be/look like?

Comment: On your "Execute Groovy Script" step, make sure in the Version drop-down that you have selected the version that you configured in Manage Jenkins, don't leave it as (Default).

Comment: Where is the "Execute Groovy Script" step? Is this supposed to be a self made node? I couldn't find the initial execute groovy script part that the plugin showed.

Comment: If you saw the previous comment before I deleted it: still having issues with the execute groovy script step.

Comment: any chance you could post your job configuration? either the config.xml or a screenshot would be super helpful.

Comment: ah ok, I see where our confusion was coming from now. I didn't realize you were talking about a Pipeline job. So I see that you're running your pipeline script from SCM. Is the script Android/btMobileApp/Jenkins_Dev a groovy script, or are you trying to call groovy from inside that script? The first option is the correct one. Pipeline jobs actually use the Pipeline: Groovy plugin (workflow-cps) so that configuration in Manage Jenkins is unnecessary. I'd try testing a pipeline job not pulling from SCM and just do a simple echo, `node {
    sh 'echo hello world'
}` to confirm it works.

Comment: Cool. I'm currently trying to call a shell script from the jenkins_dev that includes a groovy script inside of it, which is being tough. And jenkins_dev has some groovy scripting, yes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the jenkins_dev script should be all in groovy, but you can call shell scripts from that like `sh '/path/to/script'`

Comment: Hmm. Ok, I'll try that out. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug in Jenkins, but it's only affecting the view. If you click on "Groovy installations" (or any of the other installation buttons), you'll see that the state you entered, such as name, is still there.

Note that nothing is downloaded or installed when you configure tools in "Global Tool Configuration". The tools are downloaded when you use them in a build. Therefore it's important that the name of the tool in the configuration page matches the name you use in a build.

So for example, if I where to configure Maven. I would give the maven installation a name "Maven 3" in "Global Tools Configuration", and then configure my `Jenkinsfile` like this

```
node {
    stage 'Build and test'
    env.PATH = "${tool 'Maven 3'}/bin:${env.PATH}"
    checkout scm
    sh 'mvn clean install'
}
```